# B2 denials. Should I reapply?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I have been in the USA for a couple of years on an investment visa, E2, which on renewal was denied.

As I am no longer eligible for an ESTA, I applied for a B2 visa, which was denied under 214b. I have since applied 2 more times and they denied me.

I want to apply again as I want to go on holiday with my friends. I can't work out why I keep being denied.

Comment: If you are refused a visa under section 214(b), it means that you:
Did not sufficiently demonstrate that you qualify for the nonimmigrant visa category you applied for; and/or
Did not overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, required by law, by sufficiently demonstrating that you have strong ties to your home country that will compel you to leave the US at the end of your temporary stay. There’s no point in repeated applications unless your circumstances have changed significantly. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html

Comment: Significant change in circumstances what would these be?

Comment: Last time you applied, they said no because they didn't think you'd leave. Unless there's something new in your life that will convince them you'll return to your home country after your holiday (e.g., family ties, a job, property, etc) they'll just reject you again and again. I suggest that you go on holiday somewhere else that has less strenuous visa requirements. To put it bluntly, the US thinks you're trying to use your visa to get into the country and live as an illegal immigrant.

Comment: Also, I don't understand your situation. "I have been in the USA for a couple of years" means "I entered the USA a couple of years ago and I'm still there." In that case, they'll be absolutely convinced that you just want to use your tourist visa as a way to live in the USA for another couple of years. Also, what do you mean by "on an investment"?

Comment: Investment visa e2. I have been back in the uk for a couple of years now. Have a job, I rent a house, family are all here.

Comment: @Daisy How long has it been since you got your first visa refusal, and when was your most recent?

Comment: October 2016, 2017

Comment: Why was your E-2 visa refused?

Comment: The very fact that you are a UK citizen/resident (who routinely get approved for visas), and that you were previously issued an E2 visa for which for all intents and purposes one needs to satisfy a higher bar to be approved for, and then **subsequently** refused a B2 visa which is a much more common visa and easier to obtain visa says that there is some criteria you're particular failing to satisfy. If you could meet the criteria for E2 visa, you can afford legal representation without which your chances of being subsequently approved are slim and none, and you know where Slim is headed.

Answer (score 3):

Repeated refusals means that you are inherently failing to meet the requirements. This includes first of all overcoming the reason for the refusal to renew your E2 Investor visa, then establishing the credibility of your current travel plans (eg proposed length of stay and reason for travel), financial resources, and strong ties to your home country (your job, family etc) that will ensure you leave the US after a temporary visit. If your personal circumstances remain unchanged between your first (refused) and subsequent applications, you will not get a visa. At the moment based on the information you provided it looks highly probable that the authorities do not believe you intend to leave. If you’re determined to go back to the US you need to get advice from an immigration lawyer.

Comment: Agree with this. But if you are absolutely set on going you may want to hire an expert lawyer to help you review your application and history to see if there is any way you can do this. It would be unusual to go to that much trouble for a holiday though.

Comment: This would be a perfectly correct, generic answer for someone who had only ever applied for and been refused B-2 visas, but that also implies that the OP's E-2 renewal refusal has no effect on the issue (since it doesn't change the answer). I would suggest that whatever transgression caused the E-2 termination after only 2 years may in fact be the cause of the subsequent refusals, in which case changes to the OP's current personal circumstances may do very little to change the outcome of future applications since the transgression remains. She may need a lawyer to untangle that.

Comment: @Dennis Agree, my reference to ‘first, refused application’ was intended to cover this but I’ll edit my reply to clarify. Thanks